# recursive function that return the first index where sub string contained in string

Tags: c, string, recursion, strcmp, strlen

I need to make a recursive function, that gets two char arrays, and return the first index where "subStr" appear in the "str".

Signature of the function:

```
int strIndex(char str[], subStr[]);
```

For example- for str="abcdebc" and subStr="bc", it will return 1(because 1 is the first index where subStr contained in str), and for str="ab" and subStr="ab" it will return 0.
If subStr doesn't contained in str(for example str="abc", subStr="aa"), it will return -1.

This is what I tried to do:

```
int strIndex(char str[], char subStr[])
{
    if (strcmp(str, subStr) == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (strcmp(str + (strlen(str1) - strlen(subStr)), subStr) == 0)
        return strlen(str) - strlen(subStr);
    else
        //return without the last element of "str" array
}
```

but does it possible to call in recurstion without the lest element of array?

Comment: And?  We are not just going to do this for you.

Comment: Post your implementation of the recursive function and explain how it is not working as you expect.

Comment: `str2-1` ?? invalid pointer!.

Comment: Does it possible to take the last element from the array?

Comment: This is very easy using `strstr()` and doing some basic pointer arithmetik. Try it yourself! I do not see where a recursion is sensible here. Are you sure that you understood the assignment right?

Comment: This is from a test i'm solving, and I must use recursion

Comment: @jaldk try solving it with the very basics. Don't use string functions. Compare character by character and think bout how to check for a substring in a string yourself. If you have problems solving it, why don't you ask the one who gave you that test?

Answer (score 1):

The function can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int indexOf( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    size_t n1 = strlen( s1 );
    size_t n2 = strlen( s2 );

    if ( n1 < n2 )
    {        
        return -1;
    }
    else if ( strncmp( s1, s2, n2 ) == 0 )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int rtn = 1 + indexOf( s1 + 1, s2 );
        return rtn == 0 ? -1 : rtn;
    }
}    

int main( void )
{
    const char *s = "abcdebc";
    const char *t = "bc";

    printf( "Index of \"%s\" in \"%s\" is %d\n", t, s, indexOf( s, t ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
Index of "bc" in "abcdebc" is 1
```